# rating component in flex air app

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4, flex4.5

I am developing a Flex app and I need to use a rating component. 
After a wile of searching on the internet I did not found any already made component. I found one but it can't be used in flex 4.0.

As rating component I refere to something like this:
[Link1](http://www.asfusion.com/blog/entry/flex-rating-component)

Before to start developing one I want to ask if there is some open source component already developed ?

Comment: define "rating component". Also show us the one you did find, even though its not the one you want.

Comment: http://distriqt.com/native-extensions#applicationrater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used that one http://www.tink.ws/blog/ratingsbar/ and I'm satisfied with it.

Comment: I saw this post but the project is no more on the git hub. Do you stil have the project?

Comment: Yeah, I've forgot that I had to do this search ;) 
So it's here https://github.com/tinklondon/tink_flash_platform/blob/6568c4ebcc72a60771c1b93493a5e343122bc7ec/flex4.6/spark/src/ws/tink/spark/controls/RatingsBar.as